# Does nginx automatically served gzipped location matches when gzip_static is on?

Tags: nginx, gzip

I have a question about serving gzipped static files from nginx. I did `gzip -k style.min.css` to produce `style.min.css.gz` and I uploaded it to the server in the static-root directory. My location block is an exact match and looks like this:

```
location =/style.min.css {
  root /home/ubuntu/.../static-root/;
  gzip_static on;
  expires 100d;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
  access_log off;
}
```

Will nginx just serve up the `style.min.css.gz` in place of the `style.min.css` automagically, or do I have to tweak that location block so that the gzipped version is served?

Given the exact match at that location block this test does 404

```
$ curl -I https://example.com/style.css.gz -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip"
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

Is the compressed version still getting served up or do I need to tweak the location block to something like this so that the .gz file gets served?

```
location ~ /(style.min.css.*) {...
```

---

Update ... I can confirm that a gzipped version of a static css file is returned. So it seems to happen automatically. I don't know if the `gzip on;` in the server section or the `gzip_static on;` takes care of it but it is working.

```
$ curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -I https://example.com/bsmin.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=7673705, public
Cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie"
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official documentation https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/compression/ under **Sending Compressed Files**

> to service a request for /path/to/file, NGINX tries to find and send the file /path/to/file.gz. If the file doesn’t exist, or the client does not support gzip, NGINX sends the uncompressed version of the file.
>
> Note that the gzip_static directive does not enable on-the-fly compression. It merely uses a file compressed beforehand by any compression tool. To compress content (and not only static content) at runtime, use the gzip directive.